# Errors when updating @testing-library/user-event to v.14

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library, user-event

I was following all the instructions for the newest version of `@testing-library/user-event`.

BEFORE:

```
  test('request support action',() => {
    render(<SupportSection requestSupport={requestSupport} />);

    const button = screen.getByRole('button');

    userEvent.click(button);

    expect(requestSupport).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

AFTER:

```
  test('request support action', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    
    render(<SupportSection requestSupport={requestSupport} />);

    const button = screen.getByRole('button');

    await user.click(button);

    expect(requestSupport).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

`requestSupport` is mocked in the higher scope `const requestSupport = jest.fn();`

The error I'm getting is:

> TypeError: range.cloneRange is not a function

All my tests were passing before the library updates, now all failing.

Comment: Please open an issue with a reproduction https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/new?assignees=&labels=needs+assessment%2Cbug&template=bug_report.yml

Comment: Where does your error get raised? Also what version of node are you using,  as user-event no longer works with node 10.

Comment: node v.12, error occurs when I run `npm run test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution, the error occured due to some old mock, that previous test environment required. All that must be done, was to remove below from jest config file:

```
global.document.createRange = () => ({ ... });
```